# Scheduled sale ended, but variable product still appears to be on sale when viewing the product - Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

Steps to recreate this issue:

- create a variable product
- set a sale price on a variation
- set a sale schedule on a variation
- wait until after the end date
- go to frontend, view the product (or list of products), see that the sale badge and sale price are still visible
- add product to cart, open cart and see that price is correct (has been set back to regular)
- if you update the product manually in wp-admin, the issue is resolved (but this really defeats the purpose of scheduled sales)

I am using Woocommerce v2.6.14 and Wordpress v4.7.6.

If I try to check `$product->is_in_stock()` on product view, I get `1` (not correct).
If I add this product to cart and check this same thing, I get `0` (correct).

So, the issue is that the **variation price doesn't automatically update after sale end date**.

I would really appreciate every advice! :)
Thank you!

**Additional info:**

This is an image of displayed price in wp-admin after expired sale date on one product.
[image: Displayed price in wp-admin after expired sale date]

Sale price is still saved in the WC Variable object **before** it is added to cart. After a product is added to cart, min and max variation sale price is the same as regular price and everything works correctly.

If I use `$product->get_price_html();` I get wrong value before add to cart action, and if I use `$product->get_price();` I get the correct value.

**UPDATE:**
After I changed the WC version to 2.7.0 RC 1, the prices went back to correct ones, but updating WC messed up a lot of other things, so updating is not an option. Something just isn't updating correctly when the scheduled sale ends and I can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you tried switching the theme and/or disabling plugins to see if there's anything else messing with it? The usual Wordpress debugging.

Comment: I do not suggest you to Update WooCommerce but still its been 6+ months and woo 3.2.1 is live and many of the features have been modified and fixed.

Comment: Have you tried by deleting all the price cache from `wp_options` table or from WooCommerce tools?

Comment: @DerekNolan, yes I've tried, but it appears to be a Woocommerce bug.

Comment: @RaunakGupta, I've tried to delete Woocommerce and WP transients from WC System status -> Tools, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_scheduled_sales` event is what triggers the actual pricing changes to the products with scheduled sales.This event should be run once a day but maybe this does not happen.
to find sites WP Cron events you can use the below plugin :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/

by this plugin you can immediately run any cron events.you should find `woocommerce_scheduled_sales` and run it.

also you can use this code in your function theme to run event every Six hours.

```
<?php

function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
        'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );


//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_wc_scheduled_sales' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_six_hours', 'myprefix_wc_scheduled_sales' );
}


///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
 add_action( 'myprefix_wc_scheduled_sales', 'myprefix_run_wc_scheduled_sales' );
//create your function, that runs on cron
function myprefix_run_wc_scheduled_sales() {
    //your function...
    wc_scheduled_sales();
}
```